# Too many threads spawning per request in ASP.NET Core Kestrel Web Server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, threadpool, kestrel-http-server

I'm having an issue with my ASP.NET Core 3.1 Kestrel Web Server. Each request that comes in spawns way too many threads. Just for the first healthcheck request, which only responds with an "OK" string, 20+ threads will be spawned. [Thread view in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xVdM.png)

Will this affect performance? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: "no" and "not really". Most of those threads are there so that things are ready to take load. They aren't actually doing anything. They aren't per-request. If you run a few dozen requests through the server (sequentially, not overloading it) I'm guessing you'll still have the same number of threads. Also: if possible, use .NET 5 (LTS) or .NET 6 (newer features, but not LTS) - or whatever the current versions are if you're reading this in the future

Comment: @MarcGravell It's the other way around. 5 is not LTS, 6 is. Even .NET versions will always be LTS (3 years support), odd one's just "Current" (18 months support)

Comment: What @Tseng said; I mind-tripped

Comment: +100, there are normally "number of CPU threads" in the threadpool.